# How to set Windows calendar type in C#

Tags: c#, pinvoke

Is there a way to set the system calendar type using C#?

I found this function from Kernel32.dll:

```
    BOOL SetCalendarInfo(
      _In_  LCID Locale,
      _In_  CALID Calendar,
      _In_  CALTYPE CalType,
      _In_  LPCTSTR lpCalData
    );
```

How can I invoke this method within a C# application?

Comment: Why are you trying to set the os calendar type from c#? What is your requirement?

Comment: Because i want to set my Datetimepicker in my app to Hijri calender type in users computer

Comment: By the way have you considered that you can set the calendar type on your application by using the Calendar class in the System Globalisation namespace. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Globalization.Calendar%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: how ? i try to do it but not working !

Answer (score 2):

The Method signature should be the following:

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = true)]
static extern bool SetCalendarInfo(uint Locale, uint Calendar, uint CalType, 
    string lpCalData);
```

The pinvoke site is a starting point to show how to create c# method signatures for native methods but it may not always be accurate.

You will need to get familiarised with pinvoking in .net to understand how to interact with this method properly.

For additional information on the `SetCalendarInfo` method please read the MSDN documentation on it here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd374048(v=vs.85).aspx

The link below gives a good tutorial about platform invoking.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288468(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: That p/invoke is not very good. Don't believe that pinvoke.net is always accurate. It is often not. You should set CharSet to CharSet.Unicode and SetLastError to true. I see no reason why the answer should be upvoted while it has these deficiencies.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan because it helps?

Comment: I do believe it does but that is my opinion which is rather simple others may have a different opinion like that it must be correct with out a shadow of a doubt. It is relative my only error was to illicit the up vote. If anyone has a problem with my answers they can comment on them and i will endeavour to fix them until they are acceptable.

Comment: @dmportella I would have been less acidic in my comment had you not requested the upvote. The answer is still no good though. Please read all of my comment. Also, the return value should really be `bool`.

Comment: I understand no grudge i would have done the same i believe. I have add more info now as suggested by you and some additional stuff. Pinvoke is always a pain to set up because of the hunting down of correct signatures etc.

Comment: It is still incomplete. Please do read my first comment in its entirety. You missed the `SetLastError` parameter of the attribute.

Comment: Yep i had issues with the stackoverflow app  it should have added

Comment: Better. Now, you are wrong to suggest calling `GetLastWin32Error` to check for success. That's indicated by the `bool` return value. Only if the function returns `false` should you call `GetLastWin32Error`.

Comment: the other method signature would work just different way of calling it.

Comment: Not really. The answer is spot on now. There's really no other good translation of this function, apart from possibly using enums for Calendar and CalType. The error checking is really important. You don't mention it anymore, which is fine, although I fully expect that the asker will not know how to do it correctly. Almost all .net programmers get Win32 API error handling wrong.

Comment: @davidhefferman thank you for you scrutiny I prefer this way of error handling now that I can see it.

Comment: @MaxAlbish if you need anything else just create a new question or ask away but I suppose we can all agree now that this is the right way of calling the method.